# CLLocationManager bestForNavigation in background not accurate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, location, cllocationmanager

I have an app using CLLocationManager with accuracy best for navigation. I've noticed that, when the app is in foreground, everything is fine and the accuracy of the trip is perfect, but when I put the app in background the accuracy is no longer perfect, but eventually really poor.
Did someone noticed the same? There are some caveats by Apple that I missed?
Any clue to solve this problem?

```
if (!self.locManager) {
    self.locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    if ([self.locManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    self.locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    self.locManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    self.locManager.delegate=self;

//iOS 9
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
    self.locManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you are seeing?  Can you show how you have set up your `CLLocationManager` for background updates?

Comment: Just added init code... hope is clear enoght... if not just ask... thanks

Comment: When do you call `startUpdatingLocation`? From the foreground or when your app is in the background?

Comment: foreground (user is checking in a trip)

Comment: And what do you mean by "accuracy is not perfect"?  Less frequent updates?  Less horizontal accuracy?  Is the user outdoors? Indoors? In a city center with tall buildings?

Comment: Less frequent and less accurate horizontally... usually i noticed that when users are in a train: if you keep your app in FG it's more accurate then in BG...

Comment: Hmm. I haven't noticed that. If you have lower horizontal accuracy then that would typically indicate issues with GPS reception. This should be ipnothing to do with whether the app is in the foreground or background.

Comment: Less frequent updates necessarily implies less accuracy at any given time, even if the individual sample is spot on. Moreover, the phone may have switched off the GPS when you're in background and relied on cell towers and wifi. The reference does say that this accuracy setting should only be used when the device is plugged in. Is that the case for your testing?